# Search for Key & Value in JSON using C# code

Tags: c#, json

I have below json:

```
{
   "Company": {
      "tech": {
         "star": "abc.com",
         "star1": "def.com",
         "star2": "ghi.com"
      },
      "non tech": {
         "graphic": "media.com",
         "content": "xyz.com"
         
      },

      "City": "City1.com",

   },
}
```

I am using below code to read the json file ,but currently unable to read recursively and reach to inner level 
I am only able to get the first level key and value and for loop runs 2 times for the above example,Whenever a link is encountered then i have to add that in dictionary ,but for that i have to reach to inner level:

```
string jsonFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), "demo.json");

string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);

Elements= (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

// await context.PostAsync(dictObj.Keys());

findJsonValues(Elements)


 private Dictionary<string, string> findJsonValues(JObject Cat)
    {

        foreach (var pair in Cat)
        {
            string sKey = pair.Key;
            // string ln = pair.Value.ToString();
            string ss = Cat[sKey].ToString();
            if (ss.StartsWith("https"))
            {
                //Add the catalogue and link to this dictionary to create final card
                Console.WriteLine("Hey");
                Link = ss;
                //return Link;
                // Cat = null;
                //  break;


                linkDictionary.Add(sKey,ss);
                jsonIntentLimit++;
                if (jsonIntentLimit == 3)
                {
                    //call a function
                }
                continue;
            }


            jsonValues(context,(JObject)pair.Value);
        }



    }
```

Please Help.

Comment: `currently unable to read recursively`  Can you show us your attempt at reading this recursively?  I see no recursion in your current code.

Comment: Added  the recursion part.

Comment: `if (ss.StartsWith("https"))` non of the `json` above meets this, what are you expecting to happen? Are you wanting to make sure it's some kind of valid url or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this fucntion to iterate all nodes recursively

```
private static void Iterate(JToken token, Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs)
{
    if (token is JProperty && token.First is JValue)
    {
        if (!keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(((JProperty)token).Name))
            keyValuePairs.Add(((JProperty)token).Name, ((JProperty)token).Value.ToString());
    }

    foreach (JToken token2 in token.Children())
        Iterate(token2, keyValuePairs);
}
```

call this method to get all nodes

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
    var keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Iterate(token, keyValuePairs);

    foreach (var keyValue in keyValuePairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{keyValue.Key}:{keyValue.Value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, how to return back to calling function. When i use return inside recursive function to return to the calling point from the main code its not returning to the calling point but its again calling iterate function.        function iterateJson() {       //iterate over json and collect values   and then return value       this return is callingthe same function again

Comment: @AllTech, have changed the code to return the values to caller in the form of dictionary